# iOS Automatic Deployment from Command Line on Windows

Tags: ios, windows, automation

I am using the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466) to deploy an .ipa file to an iOS device from Windows.

However, I am redeploying quite frequently, and it takes almost a minute to go through the steps:
Add application, scroll down file types menu to select ipa, wait, press yes overwrite existing app, press install.

Is there a way to automate this from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [ideviceinstaller](http://quamotion.mobi/iMobileDevice/Article/ideviceinstaller) that's part of imobiledevice.

A Windows version of ideviceinstaller is available here: http://quamotion.mobi/iMobileDevice/Download

Hope it helps